# Doctrine2 One to many relation inverse side not saving owning side id

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I have 2  entities: Submission and Vote.

Submission Entity:

```
  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Votes", mappedBy="submission",cascade={"persist", "remove" })
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="submission_id")
   */
  protected $vote;

  /**
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function getVote()
  {
    return $this->vote->toArray();
  }

  /**
   * @param Votes $vote
   * @return $this
   *
   */
  public function setVote(Votes $vote)
  {
    if (!$this->vote->contains($vote)) {
      $this->vote->add($vote);
    }
    return $this;
  }
```

Vote entity:

```
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Submission", inversedBy="id")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="submission_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
   */
  protected $submission;

  /**
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function getSubmission()
  {
    return $this->submission;
  }

  /**
   * @param mixed $submission
   */
  public function setSubmission($submission)
  {
    $this->submission = $submission;
  }
```

Problem is  that  when  i'm setting vote for previously selected submission:

```
$submission = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Submission')->findOneById($submissionId);
$vote  = new Votes();
$vote->setId($submission->getId());
$vote->setFeedback($judgeComment);
$vote->setScore($judgeScore);
$vote->setSubmission($submissionId);
$submission->setVote($vote);
$em->persist($submission);
$em->flush();
```

[Vote table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8Z9k.png)

submission_id column is always NULL - i'm not sure  what i'm doing wrong. I want to store here  submission id,  for what this  vote is.

Comment: A bidirectional relationship would mean that one the one hand you have a Vote, on the other Submission. But you are inversing the relationship to the ID...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to set ids in doctrine but objects, as it is an ORM

```
$submission = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Submission')->findOneById($submissionId);
$vote  = new Votes();
$vote->setId($submission->getId()); // <--- Are you sure that you need this? 
$vote->setFeedback($judgeComment);
$vote->setScore($judgeScore);
// $vote->setSubmission($submissionId); <--- ERROR!
$vote->setSubmission($submission) // <--- Check advice below
$submission->setVote($vote);
$em->persist($submission);
$em->flush();
```

If I can also leave a suggestion here, modify `setVote` as follows

```
public function setVote(Votes $vote)
{
    if (!$this->vote->contains($vote)) {
      $this->vote->add($vote);
      $vote->setSubmission($this);
    }
    return $this;
  }
```

and you'll never need to set explicitly both sides of association anymore

I'm also noticing that your class name is plural (*should* be singular into domain) and that `vote` attribute into `submission` is singular (*should* be plural as it's a collection; you have a `-to-Many` annotation. Even the `setter` should be an `adder` as you're not setting but adding a `Vote`)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much Gerry. Thanks  to you problem is solved.  Here is  the answer:

Submission Entity:

```
  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Votes", mappedBy="submission",cascade={"persist", "remove" })
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="submission_id")
   */
  protected $vote;

  /**
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function getVote()
  {
    return $this->vote->toArray();
  }

  /**
   * @param Votes $vote
   * @return $this
   *
   */
  public function setVote(Votes $vote)
  {
    $this->vote[] = $vote;
    $vote->setSubmission($this);
    return $this;
  }
```

Vote Entity:

```
  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Submission", inversedBy="vote")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="submission_id", referencedColumnName="id",onDelete="cascade", nullable=true)
   */
  protected $submission;

  /**
   * @return mixed
   */
  public function getSubmission()
  {
    return $this->submission;
  }

  /**
   * @param mixed $submission
   */
  public function setSubmission($submission)
  {
    $this->submission = $submission;
  }
```

Now when i'm adding new  vote, everything is  fine:

```
$vote  = new Votes();
$vote->setFeedback($judgeComment);
$vote->setScore($judgeScore);
$submission->setVote($vote);
$em->persist($submission);
$em->flush();
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmDdY.png)